# Substitute of Celery in Harira

Tags: substitutions, vegetables, soup, budget-cooking

If Celery isn't available then what other vegetable or green vegetable can I use as a substitute for the making of Harira Soup?

Answer (score 1):

Celery has a very specific flavour profile.

The closest substitute for a soup would be parsley leaves and stalks.

To get even closer to the flavour, you could add celery salt or vegetable stock powder/cubes.
In my experience, the most dominant flavour by far in soup stock is the celery.

Comment: Watch out on boiling parsley in a soup. Maybe there is a way to do it, like: "don't leave it in too long"; or "don't use a certain part of the plant"; .... or *something*, but I cooked a lot of parsley in a soup once and it was quite bitter. Better to add uncooked chopped parsley at the end as a "finishing touch" -- my humble opinion. Cooking *cilantro* on the other hand, also related to celery, it came out quite tasty.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually try fennel. It will give you a lot more of the anise flavor, so perhaps don't put so much in it. A bit of fennel and parsley as suggested by Carmi might be a good combination, at least in terms of flavor.